# Reject the all other requests to reload the page except the first request

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have an issue in my project where i allow the first request ( one.jsp) to reload the page or redirect to a page , if there is a second request ( two.jsp) raised before the first request completed ( before loading one.jsppage ), then the second request should not be processed and it should be rejected.

```
<pre>
<form id = "testform" action = "form.jsp">
<input type = "hidden" name = "testhidden" value = "">
</form>

<a href = "one.jsp"> First Request</a>

<a href = "two.jsp"> Second Request</a>

<a href = "javascript:document.getElementById('testform').submit();"> third Request</a>

<a onclick = "javascript:document.getElementById('testform').submit();"> fourth Request</a>

<button onclick = "javascript:document.getElementById('testform').submit();">fifth request</button>
    </pre>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ananth3087/7cLf17bq/1/)

Actually, My requirement is that , if there a request to one page ( one.jsp) using  tag or button onclick , then that page ( one.jsp) should get load, then rejected all other requests raised  before loading page( one.jsp ).
I am looking solution for this issue in javascript or jquery. Java is optional. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post relevant code in question itself

Comment: Try event.preventDefault(); in jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 1):

Best way to restrict, you need to **unbind click event on siblings**, so once you clicked on first element other sibling elements will be disabled for click. I just added parent element div#menu for simple access!

```
$('#menu a,#menu button').click(function(){
    console.log("fire - "+$(this).text());
    $(this).siblings().unbind('click');

});
```

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cLf17bq/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unbind is not unbinding the "onclick" attribute of button or <a> tag.